# Biased coin equation when odd number of head occured

Tags: probability

Let $C$ be a biased coin such that the probability of a head turning up is $p.$ Let $p_n$ denote the probability that an odd number of heads occurs after $n$ tosses for $n \in \{0,1,2,\ldots \},$ Then which of the following is TRUE ?

$A)p_n=\dfrac{1}{2}\text{ for all }n \in \{0,1,2,\ldots \}.$

$B)p_n=(1-p)(1-p_{n-1})+p.p_{n-1}\text{ for }n\geq 1\text{ and }p_{0}=0.$

$C)p_{n}=\sum_ {i=1}^{n}p(1-2p)^{i-1} \text{ for }n\geq 1.$

$D)\text{ If } p=\dfrac{1}{2},\text{ then } p_{n}=\dfrac{1}{2} \text{ for all }n \in \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.

$E)p_{n}=1 \text{ if } n \text{ is odd and } 0 \text{ otherwise}.$

---

My approach

$P_{0}=0$

$P_{1}={H}=1/2$

$P_{2}={HT,TH}=2/4=1/2$

$P_{1}={THT,TTH,HTT,HHH}=4/8=1/2$

Now, check option B)

Here, Say for $n=3$

$(1-1/2)(1-(1/2.1/2))+1/2.(1/2.1/2)=1/2$

Is it correct?

Comment: Why do you assume in your approach that $ p = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Do note that picking well-chosen values for $p$ (for example $1$, $0$, $\frac{1}{2}$) should allow you to quickly find COUNTERexamples for most of the statements. However, what you've tried to do is prove by EXAMPLE: i.e. if a general statement holds for one particular case, it must hold in general. That's a wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any any n:

Probability of getting odd number of heads is nothing but the sum of odd terms of a binomial distribution

$(p+1-p)^n = {n\choose0}p^0(1-p)^n+{n\choose1}p(1-p)^{n-1}+{n\choose2}p^2(1-p)^{n-2}+\cdots +{n\choose n}p^n(1-p)^0 = 1\tag1$

$(1-p-p)^n = {n\choose0}p^0(1-p)^n-{n\choose1}p(1-p)^{n-1}+{n\choose2}p^2(1-p)^{n-2}+\cdots -{n\choose n}p^n(1-p)^0 = (1-2p)^n\tag2$

Subtract (2) from (1), you get terms with powers of p to be odd to have odd number of heads.

Sum of odd numbers $p_n= \frac{1}{2}[(p+1-p)^{n} - (1-2p)^{n}]$

$p_n=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-(1-2p)^n\right)$

Choice C $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p(1-2p)^i = p.\dfrac{1-(1-2p)^n}{2p} = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-(1-2p)^n\right)$
Reduces to the above expression and hence the answer is (C)

Comment: why u took $(p+1-p)^{n}?$ I have not got it.

Comment: D cannot be correct. Note that $p_0 = 0$. EDIT: On second thought, either OP made a mistake while copying, or the question is faulty, because the case $n = 0$ should be excluded for D.

Comment: He copied down the set of n to be wrong, I guess ]

Comment: @SatishRamanathan "Probability of getting odd number of heads is nothing but the sum of odd terms of a binomial distribution"- why do we do that? Binomial expansion is different from throwing biased dice. Is not it? Moreover , if there is no even number ofter , that means there is no even throw. But check for $p_{2}$ throws are {HT,TH} and probability is $\frac{1}{2}$. Is not it?

Comment: Suppose you want one head and rest of them tails, then you have the probability of  ${n\choose 1}p(1-p)^{n-1}$ number of ways the throws can play out. Now do it for three head and n-3 tails and the  ${n\choose 3}p^3(1-p)^{n-3}$ and goes on until the last term.  Hence the odd terms of the binomial is the probability that you want.

Comment: @SatishRamanathan Suppose p=1   when n=1, $P_{1}=1$.when n=2. $P_{2}=0$. when n=3 , $P_{3}=1$..........right?? but we know $P_{1}$ should be $\frac{1}{2}, because here we only consider sample space {H}.$, $P_{2}$ should be $\frac{1}{2}$, because sample spaces {HT,TH}........like this........but why not matching with option C)??

Comment: When n=1, p=1, $p_1 = 1$, Intuitively it makes sense as you have p = 100%, the one throw is defenitely heads and that the probability of odd number of heads is 1 and not $\frac{1}{2}$. When n = 2, p = 1, $p_2 = 0$.  Intuitively it makes sence as p= 1 shows the 100% the two throws are heads and that the probabiliy of odd number of heads is = 0.  Extend the same logic and you will feel very comfortable with the answer.

Comment: @SatishRamanathan but in case of $p=1$, there $P_{1}$ has will have 2 possibilities {H , T}, then how r u getting 100% probability of getting head. Similarly, when $P_{2}$ have $4$ possibilities, among which $2$ will give odd number of head i.e. {HT, TH}. Then why r u telling 100% possibility not getting head?? I have not got this point.

Comment: p=1 is a sure event.  If p=1 for getting a head, then it means that it is sure head, you will have to brush up the concept of probability. For p=1 and n=2 the two throws are heads. and odd number of heads has zero probability.  I can't explain it any further

Answer (score 0):

Proof by counterexample/elimination.

D cannot be true, as $p_0 = 0$.

Assume $ p = 1$. Then all coins are going to turn up heads. $p_n$ is 1 for odd $n$ and $0$ for even $n$.

A is now obviously false in this particular case; therefore, it cannot be a true statement in general.

Calculating $p_1$ using $B$ gives

$$ p_1 = (1 - 1)(1 - 0) + 1 \cdot 0 = 0$$

but $p_1 = 1$. So B is false.

Assume $p = 0$. Then all coins are going to turn up tails; the number of heads is always zero, so $p_n = 0$.

E is therefore false.

We conclude that C must be true, as all other statements are false.

Comment: U mean $p_{n}$ and $p$ both taking same value??

Comment: when $p_{1}=1$, why u took $p=1$?

Comment: Where do I mean that, exactly? Because $p_n \neq p$ in general.

Comment: Do you know how to prove by counterexample? You seem to be confused about how to construct proper proofs.

Comment: Then why so done in option B)?

Comment: Note that all values of $p$ I used in my argument are *assumed* - I took the liberty to pick a value for $p$, and tried to find a contradiction for that particular case.

Comment: ok, got it . Now Say in option C) , if I put p=1/2, then value of $p_{n}$ turns to $0.$ Then how u can say C) as correct option?

Comment: I assumed this was a multiple choice question with only one right answer - but as you point out, there are actually *no* right answers.

Comment: Why do u think, there is no right ans??

Comment: Because, by including the case $n = 0$, D isn't actually correct. I proved A, B, D, E were false - you pointed out C is false too.

Comment: Why $p_{0}$ cannot be $1/2?$, It is not written in question anywhere that $p_{0}$ always need to be 0. And in option D) told only when $p=1/2$ then all of $p_{n}$ should be $1/2.$ Putting $p=1/2$, we got $p_{n}=1/2.$ So, it is not depending on $n$. Right??

Comment: ok, U mean $p_{0}=0$ and all other $p_{i}=1/2$ where $i=1,2....n$, that will be case. right?? So, all options fails here.

Comment: P_0 is ALWAYS 0. How can you throw an odd number of heads after zero throws? Yes, your second comment is what I meant.